# MariaDB Avoid Deadlocks

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, deadlock, galera

My original error was

> Error No: 1213 - Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try
>   restarting transaction

Okay, so I wrote a loop with max retries and a wait in between to try and get through the deadlocks.

```
$Try = 0;
while (!$Result = $dbs->query($MySQL)) {
    $Try++;
    if ($Try === MYSQL_MAX_RETRIES)
        HandleMySQLError($dbs->error, $MySQL, false, $Test, $Trace);
    else 
        sleep(MYSQL_RETRY_WAIT);
}
```

But now I'm constantly getting some of the original error still, and a new error

> Got error 35 "Resource deadlock avoided" during COMMIT

But I can't really seem to find out what this means or how to fix it?

---

**EDIT**

I left out a ton of information when I first wrote this, but the server is a RedHat 7 AWS EC2 (well, 3 of them) in a Galera & MariaDB cluster.

The query I am running is a call to a stored procedure

```
call`getchatmessages`('<ChatID>','<UserID>',from_unixtime('<Some Timestamp>'));
```

And the stored procedure is as follows

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `getchatmessages`(IN `__ChatID` CHAR(36), IN `__UserID` CHAR(36), IN `__Timestamp` TIMESTAMP(6))
BEGIN

DECLARE `__NewChatMessages` TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE `__i` INT(11) DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE `__Interval` INT(11) DEFAULT 100; -- ms
DECLARE `__Timeout` INT(11) DEFAULT 15000; -- ms

while `__NewChatMessages`=0 and `__i`<`__Timeout`/`__Interval` do
    select 1 into `__NewChatMessages` from `chatmessages` where `ChatID`=`__ChatID` and `DateTimeAdded`>ifnull(`__Timestamp`,0) limit 1;
    update `chatusers` set `DateTimeRead`=now(6) where `ChatID`=`__ChatID` and `UserID`=`__UserID`;
    do sleep(`__Interval`/1000);
    set `__i`=`__i`+1;
end while;

select `chatmessages`.`Body`, `chatmessages`.`ChatID`, `chatmessages`.`UserID`, 
`chatmessages`.`ChatMessageID`, `chatmessages`.`DateTimeAdded`, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`chatmessages`.`DateTimeAdded`) `Timestamp`, `users`.`FirstName`,
`users`.`LastName`
from `chatmessages` 
join `users` using (`UserID`) 
where `chatmessages`.`ChatID`=`__ChatID` 
and `chatmessages`.`DateTimeAdded`>ifnull(`__Timestamp`,0) 
order by `chatmessages`.`DateTimeAdded` desc
limit 100;

END
```

Comment: What's the query?

Comment: @ethrbunny It's a stored procedure, I've added the call and the procedure to the end of the post

Comment: .. and there aren't any triggers or FKs on those tables?

Comment: @ethrbunny There are not any triggers on the table that's being updated there, but there are definitely multiple foreign keys on just about every table involved, do foreign keys cause cluster issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deadlock in Galera Cluster (MariaDB Galera Cluster, 3 nodes) is not a typical deadlock, but a way of communicating the multi-master conflicts:

http://galeracluster.com/documentation-webpages/dealingwithmultimasterconflicts.html

The easiest way to avoid deadlocks is to write to 1 node at a time, i.e. configure HA proxy to write to 1 node only. In your case you will run sp on Node1 (does not matter which node, but always on 1 node, sort of "sticky sessions").

More information here: https://severalnines.com/blog/avoiding-deadlocks-galera-set-haproxy-single-node-writes-and-multi-node-reads

Comment: Seems you may be correct, I'm currently using AWS ELB, so I don't think it has the option to only keep one for writes like HA proxy does, if only enable one of my instances in the ELB it does work though. Looks like I'll have to setup a HA proxy node or two. I'll check back with my results

Comment: You can try (just for test) to connect directly to 1 node and run your test

Comment: I have this set up and working correctly with HA Proxy, I modified my application to send everything that doesn't start with "select" to the first node and then round robin the rest and I haven't had a problem since

Comment: With the small exception of some select queries that select data right after it's been inserted (like to get the last auto incremented number for say an Invoice number, being selected with the Invoice ID) and the select hits a node that the data hasn't propagated to yet, those one I have the option of sending to the writes connection

Answer (score 0):

Is this Proc being called inside a transaction?  If so, I argue strongly with its design.  You have a loop with a sleep hanging onto the transaction.

Instead, have the `UPDATE` be a transaction by itself.

This may virtually eliminate the deadlocks.  However you should still deal with deadlocks, as discussed by other answer(s).

**Edit** Since there are no `BEGINs`, and `autocommit=ON`, the OP is already following this advice.  Alas.

Comment: Unless transactions are implied when the connection is created and exist for the remainder of the PHP script, I am under the impression that the call in the loop is it's own transaction since I never explicitly started or ended any transactions, although I could be wrong about my assumptions

Comment: You have no `BEGIN` and autocommit = 1?

Comment: No I do not, should I?

Comment: I think it the existence/absence of `BEGIN` and the value of `autocommit` are critical to figuring out the deadlocks.  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'autocommit';`.  Is the PHP script yours, or is it some 3rd party software?

Comment: Oh my bad yes, autocommit is ON, and I don't have any begins, this is entirely my script (it's a very big script, >~8,000 lines)

Comment: Then each SQL statement is its own transaction.  Which is consistent with what I was proposing in my Answer.  So, back to "square 0".  I don't have a way to help eliminate deadlocks.